# Owning side not containing id of table

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, postman, java-ee-6

**Spring boot REST API**

I create two entity in Student

```
package com.practice.lab.entities;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Student extends BaseEntity{
    String name;
    double marks;
    int age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Bike> bike;

    public Student(String name, double marks, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.marks = marks;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

then I have another entity Bike

```
package com.practice.lab.entities;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Bike extends BaseEntity{
    String companyname;
    int model;
    double price;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "stu_id")
    Student student;
}
```

"inside my StudentController"

```
@GetMapping
    public List<Student> fetchAllStudent(){
        System.out.println("Fetching all student");
        return  studentService.getAllStudent();
    }

@PostMapping
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        System.out.println("Adding emp");
        return userService.addUserDetails(user);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl6TR.png) POST request to add Student with bike

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh4dC.png) Students and Bike added but id not added in table

Why am I not getting Student id in Bike table

Comment: There's no id field in the `Student` class, so what id to you expect there?

Comment: do you have `@MappedSuperclass` in `BaseEntity` ?

Comment: @Anon yes I have created BAse Entity as mappedSuperClass

Comment: show the post service method and the repository used

Comment: `@PostMapping
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        System.out.println("Adding emp");
        return userService.addUserDetails(user);
    }`

Comment: just show every relevant code. this includes `userService class and its methods atleast the userService.addUserDetails(user); `   `BaseEntity` and the corresponding  repositories